# How to approach user stories in a Billing System Migration project?

Tags: migration, user-stories

Our project is mainly driven by cost reduction. To do so, billing will be migrated from a legacy system to a newer and improved system.

Customers won't notice a difference. Neither will the end user placing the order's on their behalf. The whole project changes the behind the scenes. Does this mean this project is not fit for Agile?

Comment: Agile is a development methodology and can be applied to any development project. The question you should really be asking yourself and your team is "Do we want to work on this project using Agile principles?"

Comment: Let me clarify, but the question is how to approach user stories. Forget "Agile". Or are you implying we shouldn't because not suitable for this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Any project with a significant number of unknowns is appropriate for Agile. Wysocki ("Effective Project Management") has suggested this is 80% of all projects! Like him, I might use waterfall for highly repeatable projects like small software implementations in stable environments, but I would certainly use an Agile method like Scrum for any migration project. I have been involved in those, and they are full of unknowns.

In response to your comment: Excellent question! User stories are perhaps misnamed, because they can be about more than just users. Different coaches use different categories, but generally you can think of them as anything the team needs to do: user/customer requirements; market (future needs) requirements; business requirements, those things other parts of the business need from the team; and technical requirements, stuff the team needs to do "under the hood." As long as it is small enough to complete within a sprint, it's legitimate to use as a story! My (free, open source) Full Stack Scrum site has a details on [Requirement Types](http://fullstackscrum.net/get-teams-started/#_Toc489291940).

Comment: Any suggestion to approach user stories when the user experience is not changing at all?